# undefined method `name_path' in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**i have the following code:**

```
<%@menus.each do |d|%>
  <%= d.menu_item_name%>
  <%= d.price%> 
  <%= link_to 'Add to cart', name_path(d.id) %>
```

In controller:

```
before_action :find_hotel, only: [:show,:name,:new,:create,:index,:set_country]
def index
  #@menus=Menu.where(:hotel_id=>@hotel.id).sorted
  @menus=@hotel.menus.sorted
end

def show
  @menu=Menu.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @menu=Menu.new
end

def create
end

def find_hotel
  if params[:hotel_id]
    @hotel=Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
  end
end

def name
  session[:menu_name] = @menu_item .menu_item_name
  redirect_to find_hotel_path
end

def set_country
  @menu_item = Menu.find(params[:id])
end
```

in routes:

```
resources :line_items

resources :carts

get 'menus/index'

get 'menus/show'

get 'menus/new'

get 'menus/create'

get 'hotels/index'

get 'hotels/show'

root 'homepage#index'
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:option)',:via=>[:get,:post]
```

Comment: Can you share your routes.rb file ?

Comment: You can use show routes to view your current routes with methods for them. Obviously, last line will not create methods for all your actions, like `name`, cause it doesn't know them.

Comment: For readability, it's a good idea to make callbacks private. The find_hotel should be a private method

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any routes in your `routes.rb` file that point you `name_path`.

I think you are trying to create cart item so you do have `resources :carts` in your routes file. try use `cart_path` instead of `name_path`. Also create action did not take any id unless it's a nested resource.

Answer (score 1):

**Error**

The error you receive is because you're calling `name_path(...)`

This would be fine, except you don't have a method called `name_path` defined - hence the error. The trick is to know where this "method" would be found, and then create it properly:

---

**Routes**

Your problem is you don't have a "name" path in your routes, moreover I think you could construct your controller structure, and routes, much more coherently:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :menus, only: [:index, :show, :create, :new] do
   get :name #-> domain.com/menus/:id/name
end
```

This will give you the ability to call the following:

```
<%= link_to 'Add to cart', menu_name_path(d.id) %>
```

---

**Controller**

I see you're attempting to implement a cart interface, you'd be much better creating an `add` method to your `carts_controller` instead:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :carts do
   post :add #-> domain.com/carts/:id/add
end
```

This will allow you to use the following functionality:

```
#app/controllers/carts_controller.rb
class CartsController < ApplicationController
   def add
      session[:cart][:products] << params[:id]
   end
end
```

Of course, a little abstract, but it may help you add some more structure to your application

Comment: Thanks, for your comment. I just didn't understand, why he expects such route, maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to say why do you expect this route, but i'll try to predict that your last line should handle all actions and make routes (short methods) from them. As I said in comment, last line will not create methods for all your actions. It's better to use `resource` for this:

```
resources :menus, only: [:index, :show, :new] do
  collection do
    get :create
    get :name
  end
end
```

It will create routes methods like `name_menus_path`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where 'name_path' has come from. From looking at your code I assume you mean

```
     menu_path
```